# Is Saudi Arabia intent on addressing the Palestinian component while negotiating a normalization deal without Palestine at the negotiating table?

Tags: israel, palestine, saudi-arabia, negotiation

> Past agreements between Egypt and Jordan tried but ultimately failed
> to elevate the importance of the Palestinians, and the Oslo process
> that started nearly 30 years ago ground to a halt for many reasons.
> The 2020 Abraham Accords with the United Arab Emirates, Bahrain, and
> Morocco functioned like a road in the West Bank that circumvents
> Palestinian population centers and goes directly to Israeli
> settlements. There are many reasons why Israeli-Palestinian tensions
> remain high, a primary one being the lack of a just resolution that
> accounts for the interests of the Palestinian people. **An Israel-Saudi
> normalization accord that doesn’t adequately address the Palestinian
> component would suffer from the same vulnerabilities as these past
> deals, and Saudi Arabia cannot risk a deal that isn’t as comprehensive
> as possible given its leadership position in the broader Muslim and
> Arab world.** The criticisms and blowback it could receive from regional
> actors, including Iran, other Gulf states like Qatar, and associated
> media outlets, may be more considerable than what the United Arab
> Emirates, Bahrain, and Morocco experienced in 2020. In addition, after
> years of committing several unforced errors in its regional policies
> on Yemen, Qatar, and Lebanon, the Saudi leadership may be much more
> cautious in evaluating the potential risks of proceeding with Israel
> without some guarantees for the Palestinians.

https://israelpolicyforum.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/Navigating-Normalization-The-U.S.-Saudi-Arabia-and-the-Israeli-Palestinian-Arena-102023.pdf

Is Saudi Arabia intent on addressing the Palestinian component while negotiating a normalization deal without Palestine at the negotiating table? I was reading this article about the possibility of an Israel-Saudi normalization deal and it seems that the Saudi are intent on negotiating it without representatives of Palestine sitting at the negotiating table. How does Saudi Arabia plan to adequately address the Palestinian concerns without them sitting at the negotiating table? Any statement in the public domain that addresses this question?

Comment: Who knows what MBS is really planning. Official answers will be vague until the deal is done. I did watch an interview with him. (The famous one just before the Oct 7 attacks.) https://youtu.be/w0NxI44yBDM?t=230

Comment: Media in the Muslim world have failed to avert their eyes as skillfully as their Western counterparts. The global outrage is real, and in the case of the Kingdom, very near. The Saudi position has thus been changing. But if played skillfully, the Kingdom now has additional leverage in its ongoing negotiations with Israel. Such dealings will go on regardless. They're both significant regional powers, can't avoid interacting, whatever the rhetoric.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was reading this article about the possibility of an Israel-Saudi normalization deal and it seems that the Saudi are intent on negotiating it without representatives of Palestine sitting at the negotiating table.

Why would *Saudi* normalization with Israel have *Palestinians* at the table?

No, Saudis do not want to tie their own economic and military interests with the Palestinians, especially not with those in Gaza. Hamas is aligned with Iran, which is not a Saudi friend, in fact the Saudi-Israeli thaw is driven largely by the shared interests against Iran. Accordingly, one major motivation for the Palestinian attack on October 7th was to derail that thaw.

The Saudis tried to tie the normalization talks to the Palestinian problem before, and [it didn't go very far](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_Peace_Initiative).

Comment: MBS [claims](https://youtu.be/w0NxI44yBDM?t=230) otherwise in re taking Palestinian interest into account in order to get a comprehensive deal . Whether he really means it... There's no democracy in Saudi Arabia, but assassinations, coups etc. do happen. See Sadat.

Comment: Of course he *says*, but what does he do? There was very little retaliation against Israel in the Arab world following the events of October 7th, if it all, in stark contrast to the previous rounds of violence. There's also very different reaction when it comes to the West Bank. I think even the Saudis understand that the Palestinian problem will not be solved as long as *the Palestinians* don't want it solved, and they're tired of waiting.